# Modulo operator gives unexpected output in Java

Tags: java, mathematical-optimization, modulo, floating-accuracy

I have the following, working method in Java:

```
/**
 * Determines if n is a power of z
 * 
 * @param z the number that n may be a power of
 * @param n the number that may be a power of z
 * @return true if n is a power of z 
 */
public boolean isPowerOf(int z, int n) {
    double output = Math.log(n) / Math.log(z);
    if(output % 1 > 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

isPowerOf(3, 729); //returns true, because 3^6 = 729
```

Works fine n mighty, but I tried it differently the first time:

```
public boolean isPowerOf(int z, int n) {
    double output = Math.log(n) % Math.log(z);
    if(output != 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, for `log(729) % log(3)` seems to return `1.0986122886681093`, while the outcome of `log(729) / log(3) is 6`.

Anyone able to tell me what causes the modulo operator to still give `1.09` remainder here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Anyone able to tell me what causes the modulo operator to still give 1.09 remainder here?

The normal floating point inaccuracies, basically. The values you're using aren't *exactly* log(729) and log(3). If you look at `log(3)` and `log(729) % log(3)` you'll see they're almost exactly the same:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x = Math.log(729);
        double y = Math.log(3);
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
        System.out.println(x % y);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
6.591673732008658
1.0986122886681098
1.0986122886681093
```

In other words, `log(729)` is effectively `log(3) * 5.9999999999999` (or something similar). You'll probably want to add some tolerance to your test, basically, and return whether or not the remainder is *very close to 0* or *very close to the `log(z)`*.

Alternatively, use `log` and division to work out "roughly" what the power should be, then `Math.pow` to check for the exact value:

```
int power = (int) (Math.log(n) / Math.log(z) + 0.5);
return n == Math.pow(z, power);
```

Here you should be okay in terms of floating point inaccuracies until the numbers get "pretty big". You can use `BigInteger` if you want to cope with *very* big numbers precisely.

Answer (score 2):

```
Math.log(729)  = 6.591673732008658
Math.log(3) = 1.0986122886681098

d= 1.0986122886681093
```

If you notice, `d (1.0986122886681093)` is slightly smaller(last digit) than  `Math.log(3)-(1.0986122886681098)` value add it seems to be working fine.  Probably you are missing the double data type precision understanding. **Floating point numbers have some inaccuracies for high precision values because of their actual representation.**